# Allowing user to input how many decimals wanted, calculate percentage

Tags: python, input

```
numerator = int(input("Please enter the numerator: "))
denominator = int(input("Please enter the denominator: "))
decimal = int(input("Please enter the number of decimal places: "))
percent = numerator/denominator
format_string = "{:.2f}".format(percent)
```

I changed the `.2` in the format_string to decimal as in `{:.decimalf}` to allow the user to decide how many decimal places. Python does not allow me to use a variable for this for some reason.

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use f-strings like so:

```
format_string = f"{percent:.{decimal}f}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
format_string = "{:.{decimal}f}".format(percent, decimal=decimal)
```

or even:

```
format_string = "{:.{}f}".format(percent, decimal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape braces in format string by doubling them

```
decimal_places = 4
format_string = "{{:.{}f}}".format(decimal_places)  # '{:.4f}'
format_string.format(1/2)  # '0.5000'
```